# How can I reuse big objects in several tests while using testthat?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm following the advice in [the R packages book](https://r-pkgs.org) to use `testthat` in the package I'm developing. There are several tests that first need to create an object before proceeding with the test, and it takes a long time to create this object.

Is there a way to create the object just once and reuse it in every other test that needs it? The book recommends not to store data files bigger than 1MB because of CRAN restrictions, and this is >20MB. I have looked into saving it as a temp file using `withr::local_tempfile` but that only works for one test (the file gets destroyed after the one test is done).

Comment: I think the recommended way is to _not_ run those tests on CRAN (`testthat::skip_on_cran()`). As for how to run it efficiently in your CI or local environment, I tend to run the generating code outside of a `testthat::test_that` code block but still within an `expect_*` expression. This means the object will be available to other `test_that(...)` blocks and will be collected/discarded when the file is complete. (This is assuming that creation of the object is itself a test; if it's not testable, then the issue becomes much simpler.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm afraid I don't understand how defining it within an `expect_*` expression will make it available to other `test_that(...)` blocks. Could you please provide a short example?

Comment: Expressions run within `test_that` are run within their own environment, so objects created in one `test_that` block are not available outside of it. However, `expect_*` does not follow that, so if you have an `expect_*` outside of `test_that`, you can still set an expectation (e.g., `expect_true(nrow(newobj <- myfunc(...)) > 0)`), and then use that produced object later in the file's environment (including within `test_that` blocks). If you're looking to make the object available to tests in other files, though, you'll need to use some form of `setup.R`.